# Slice two boxes HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

can be done a slice between two divs in CSS like the following photo ?
[image]

I tried to google it but didn't found anything usefull for my problem

Thanks !

Comment: yes, you can do using css3.

Comment: @nareshkumar can you give me a tutorial or an example ?

Comment: ok. here is a link, it will show how to draw your custom shape using css. http://codepen.io/jotavejv/pen/hacBm

Comment: wondering why imgur deleted that pic, or did you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to do it with `image` .
But if you want to do with css , here is example ,

**css**

```
.parallelogram { width: 150px; height: 100px; -webkit-transform: skew(20deg);   
-moz-transform: skew(20deg); -o-transform: skew(20deg); background: red;   
float:left;margin-left:18px;margin-right:8px;}
.parallelogram2 { width: 150px; height: 100px; -webkit-transform: skew(20deg);   
-moz-transform: skew(20deg); -o-transform: skew(20deg); background: Black;float:left; }
```

**html**

```
<div class="parallelogram"></div>
<div class="parallelogram2"></div>
```

[Fiddle example !](http://jsfiddle.net/hRfFb/)

And you can check and learn how css shapes works [here](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/) and [here](http://www.css3shapes.com/) !
Good Luck !